# DQL - extract year from datetime format

Tags: symfony, dql

How do I extract distinct years from datetime format (00-00-0000 00:00:00)? I'm using Symfony 2 and DQL.

In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT extract(year FROM created_at) 
FROM news 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

**edit:**

solution with SUBSTRING:

group by year (datetime format Y-m-d H:i:s):

```
SELECT p, SUBSTRING(p.created_at, 1, 4) as year
FROM news p
GROUP BY year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use [Native SQL and custom hydration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own EXTRACT function.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html